# Firebase Cloud Functions - Issues with Promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, promise, google-cloud-functions

When running my Firebase Cloud Function `orgNew` there seems to be something not working correctly with my promises and the order in which the code is executed.

**Console log (shortened):**

```
1: Function execution started
2: function checkLicenseKey() was successful
3: function checkPermissionsFromAuth() was successful 
4: result undefined
5: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined // Points to marked spot in code 
6: Unhandled error Error: Unknown error code: failed to connect.
7: Function execution took 4663 ms, finished with status code: 500 
8: function getUserAuthObject() was successful { userObj is logged here }
```

**My Firebase Cloud Function with some extra code (shortened):**

```js
exports.orgNew = functions
  .region("europe-west3")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {

      var userObj;
      var orgID;
      return (
        checkLicenseKey(data.licenseKey)
          .then((result) => {
            if (!result.isValid) {
              throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                "permission-denied",
                "Invalid license key used"
              );
            }
            return checkPermissionsFromAuth(context);
          })
          .then((result) => {
            return getUserAuthObject(context.auth.uid);
          })
          .then((result) => {
            console.info(result); // Error: result is undefined (line 4 in console)!
            userObj = result; // Therefore userObj is also undefined!
            return createOrganization(data, userObj);
 //  It seems that this gets executed even when if my userObj isn't ready yet!
          })
          .then((result) => {
            orgID = result.id;
            return loadDataFromTemplate(orgID, context);
          })
          .then((result) => {
            return addMember(orgID, userObj);
          })
          .then((result) => {
            return sendConfirmation(userObj.email, userObj.displayName);
          })
          .then((result) => {
            return { orgID, success: true };
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // handle error
            functions.logger.error("Error:", err);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed to connect");
          })
      );
  });

function createOrganization(data, userObj) {
    const organisationRef = admin.firestore().collection("org");
    const document = {
      title: data.title,
      description: data.description,
      meta: {
        id: organisationRef.id,
        creator: {
// Error points to the following line, obviously this is because userObj is still undefined.
          creatorUID: userObj.uid,
          creatorEmail: userObj.email,
          creatorName: userObj.displayName,
        },
        createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      },
      },
    };
    return organisationRef
      .add(document)
      .then((organisationRef) => {
        functions.logger.info("function createOrganization() was successful");
        return organisationRef;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        functions.logger.error("Error creating organization: ", error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed to connect", error);
      });
  }
  
  function getUserAuthObject(uid) {
    admin
      .auth()
      .getUser(uid)
      .then((userRecord) => {
        const obj = {
          uid: userRecord.uid,
          email: userRecord.email,
          displayName: userRecord.displayName,
        };
        return obj;
      })
      .then((result) => {
        functions.logger.info("function getUserAuthObject() was successful", result);
        return result
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        functions.logger.error("Error fetching user data:", err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed to connect");
      });
  }
```

All the other functions are not included here because they aren't involved in the problem.

**Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!**

Comment: Unrelated note: You could also execute the `loadDataFromTemplate`, `addMember` and `sendConfirmation` calls in parallel using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as they don't appear to be dependent on each other.

Comment: @samthecodingman Great suggestion, I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the code (i.e. without testing) it seems it is because you don't return the [Promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) in the `getUserAuthObject()` function. Therefore `userObj` is undefined.

You should adapt it as follows:

```
  function getUserAuthObject(uid) {
    return admin  // !!! See the return here !!!
      .auth()
      .getUser(uid)
      .then((userRecord) => {
        const obj = {
          uid: userRecord.uid,
          email: userRecord.email,
          displayName: userRecord.displayName,
        };
        functions.logger.info("function getUserAuthObject() was successful", obj);
        return obj;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        functions.logger.error("Error fetching user data:", err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed to connect");
      });
  }
```

---

BTW, see how we can simplify the Promises chain in this function since you don't need to do

```
    return obj;
  })
  .then((result) => {
    functions.logger.info("function getUserAuthObject() was successful", result);
    return result
  })
```

since `obj` does not return a Promise. It is not wrong, since [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) returns a Promise but it is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Very simple but I missed it. Yes, I'm a bit unhappy with the superfluous part. Will fix that too.